# Drupal.t() and language code

Tags: javascript, i18n-l10n

I want to write some JavaScript code for my project. I need to use `Drupal.t()`, but it seems that `Drupal.t()` only accepts English, and I don't want to write my JavaScript in English.

Is there any way to inform `Drupal.t()` that my string is not in English, just like `t()` that let you specify the language code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string that you pass as first argument to `Drupal.t()` (as it happens with [t()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7)) needs to be in English, since the function translates a string from English to another language.

Differently from `t()`, which allows you to pass the language code for the language you want to translate the string, `Drupal.t()` doesn't have that possibility. Its arguments are the following:

- str
  A string containing the English string to translate.
- args
  An object of replacements pairs to make after translation. Incidence of any key in this array are replaced with the corresponding value. See Drupal.formatString().
- options

  - 'context' (defaults to the empty context): The context the source string belongs to.

#### Reference

- [The content of drupal.js](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x:/misc/drupal.js), the file containing `Drupal.t()`

Answer (score 0):

Nope, not really. Drupal is built from ground up in English and that's the way you need to build your modules too. Some parts of the code tries to enable you provide default texts in another languages, but it's a disaster if you decide to change default language later.

It is possible to built functionality like you need in a custom module, it is even possible someone did, but I don't know of any reliable solution.